# How to activate bracketed paste mode in GNOME Terminal for Vim inside tmux

Tags: cut-copy-paste, terminal, tmux

**Edit** this issue happens inside a tmux session. The original value of $TERM before starting vim is:

```
echo $TERM
screen
```

The issue appears for example when pasting this kind of indented code:

```
def function(condition):
    if condition:
        print("Hi")
    if not condition:
        print("Bye")
```

When I press  `Ctrl+Shift+V` in vim's insert mode, auto indentation messes-up the output and this is what appears:

[image]

I have to set vim to paste mode `:set paste` to have the pasted text indented correctly:

[image]

I then have to remember to deactivate it with `:set nopaste`.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522/2641825) says that vim can enter and exit automatically from paste mode with bracketed paste mode. It is even supposed to be by default in Vim 8. I have vim 8, how to enable bracketed paste mode for gnome terminal?

Comment: See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25157/18609) and also the comments there. If you use `export TERM=gnome-256color` in your shell before you start Vim, does that make bracketed mode work? Please [edit] the question to include your original value of `$TERM` before you change it with this suggestion...

Comment: You might also like [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24929/18609) with some recommendations on how to manage `set paste` a bit more automatically (particularly disabling it right after pasting and exiting insert mode.)

Comment: You can use the `unnamed` register to paste with `"*p`. You'll need the `clipboard` feature (`:version`) to do so. This will preserve the indentation.

Comment: The only reason not to migrate this back to SU is to avoid shuffling the question around... but honestly I'm not sure it belongs here if the question is "how to enable bracketed paste in Gnome terminal." (FWIW, my vim uses bracketed paste, but I did have to enable it in `~/.inputrc` with `set enable-bracketed-paste on`)

Comment: @filbranden I did `export TERM=gnome-256color` before starting vim but still have the indentation issue.

Comment: @PaulRougieux See @user938371's answer! I'm sure that'll be the most comprehensive answer you'll get on this, if anyone knows this stuff @user938271 is the one who does! Follow up on that answer with comments if it's still not working for you. Yeah and apparently you need `TERM=xterm-256color`, so configure your GNOME Terminal to do that (it might actually be the default.)

Comment: @filbranden adding `export TERM=xterm-256color` to `.bashrc` solves the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is even supposed to be by default in Vim 8.

Only if Vim thinks the terminal is xterm-compatible, which is the case if `TERM` is `xterm` or some derivative.
If `TERM` is `gnome`, Vim won't enable the bracketed paste mode automatically; you have to configure it.

> I have vim 8, how to enable bracketed paste mode for gnome terminal?

Try this:

```
if &t_BE == ''
    let &t_BE = "\e[?2004h"
    let &t_BD = "\e[?2004l"
    let &t_PS = "\e[200~"
    let &t_PE = "\e[201~"
endif
```

`t_BE`, `t_BD`, `t_PS` and `t_PE` are all terminal options.  The first two are sent automatically to the terminal whenever it enters/leaves raw mode; they must be set correctly so that they enable/disable the bracketed paste mode.

The sequences `\e?2004h` and `\e?2004l` are documented in [xterm's documentation](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_).  Look for `CSI ? Pm h` (or `CSI ? Pm l`), then for `Ps = 2 0 0 4`.

> Ps = 2 0 0 4  ⇒  Set bracketed paste mode, xterm.
> ...
> Ps = 2 0 0 4  ⇒  Reset bracketed paste mode, xterm.

`t_PS` and `t_PE` tell Vim which sequences the terminal will use to surround the pasted text.  The values are documented [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode).

---

To test the code, start Vim like this:

```
vim +'let @+ = "clipboard\e:echom \"malicious code injected\"\ri"' +startinsert
```

Then press `C-S-v` to insert the contents of the clipboard in the Vim buffer.
If the only text which is inserted is `clipboard` and `:mess` has logged `malicious code injected`, then it doesn't work.

---

Note that the bracketed paste mode can be bypassed if the pasted text contains `\e[201~`; the latter sequence *may* end the bracketed mode prematurely.  See the second example on [this page](https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste).  It doesn't work on all terminals though; see [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/184112) for more info.

Also, the bracketed paste mode does not prevent Vim from auto-indenting the text when inserting the contents of a register with `C-r`.

```
$ vim -Nu NONE +'set ai' +':let @a = "Level 1\n    Level 2\n    Level 2\nLevel 1"'
" press:  i C-r a
```

If `'paste'` is reset, you'll get:

```
Level 1
    Level 2
        Level 2
        Level 1
```

If `'paste'` is set, you'll get:

```
Level 1
    Level 2
    Level 2
Level 1
```

You can avoid this issue by pasting from normal mode (`"ap`), or inserting with `C-r C-o` or `C-r C-p`.

FWIW, for this reason, I use these mappings:

```
ino <expr> <c-r> getregtype(v:register) =~# '<c-v>' ? '<c-r>' : '<c-r><c-o>'
ino <c-r><c-p> <c-r><c-p>
ino <c-r><c-o> <c-r><c-o>
ino <c-r><c-r> <c-r><c-r>
```

---

If you use tmux, be aware that the latter supports the bracketed paste mode since version 1.7, but it doesn't use it by default.  In the key bindings table, `]` is bound to the `paste-buffer` command:

```
bind-key    -T prefix       ]                     paste-buffer
```

If you want paste bracket control codes to be inserted around the buffer, you need to pass the `-p` flag to `paste-buffer`.  FWIW, I use it in these 3 key bindings:

```
bind C-p paste-buffer -p
bind p choose-buffer -Z -F "#{buffer_sample}" "paste-buffer -p -b '%%'"
bind -T copy-mode-vi p send -X copy-selection-and-cancel \; paste-buffer -p \; delete-buffer
```

Update: This was changed in [3f6af41](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/3f6af4156f451cfbee867babe74cc6675eb3f947).

---

For more info, see [`:h xterm-bracketed-paste`](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste).

Comment: Thanks I'd like to accept your answer since it is well documented, but the solution to my question was simply to add `export TERM=xterm-256color` to my `~/.bash_aliases`. After I did that, bracketed paste worked in vim, i.e. vim didn't mess-up with indentation as illustrated in my OP above.

Comment: @PaulRougieux That's actually in the first line of the answer: *"Only if Vim thinks the terminal is xterm-compatible, which is the case if `TERM` is `xterm` or some derivative."*

Comment: @PaulRougieux It was not *the* solution, but *a* solution.  You can post your solution, and even accept it if you think it's the right one; there's nothing wrong with that.  Personally, I prefer setting `TERM` with the value `gnome-256color` in a gnome terminal, and setting Vim options rather than lying about the terminal's identity to all applications.

Comment: You could argue that the current answer also contains a lie since it sets the options regardless of the terminal's identity, which means it tells Vim that the terminal supports the bracketed paste mode, while maybe it does not.  This is true, but: 1. you can make the `if &t_BE` guard more sophisticated and use various heuristics to guess whether the terminal can truly support bracketed paste mode and if so how; 2. this lie only affects Vim, it does not affect *all* the applications running in the terminal contrary to `TERM`.

Comment: This answer to the question [How to configure gnome-terminal to use xterm-256color by default?](https://superuser.com/a/870547/419414) suggest putting ` TERM=xterm-256color` inside gnome terminal's profile preference rather than in the `.bashrc` so I put it there instead.

Comment: @user938271 thanks for the insights. It's not clear to me what vim settings need to be modified if I only have `TERM=gnome-256color`. Why do I have to set t_BE, t_BD, t_PS and t_PE terminal options. Why is there not a simple variable to activate bracketed paste? I'll reconsider the more complex setup if I encounter issues with the fact that I have set-up gnome terminal to lie about it's `TERM=xterm-256color` status.

Comment: Also note that: "Beginning with gnome-terminal version 3.16, it defaults to `TERM=xterm-256color`" so maybe you don't need to set anything anymore? (Assuming you have a fairly recent Linux distribution installed...)

Comment: *"Why do I have to set t_BE, t_BD, t_PS and t_PE terminal options. Why is there not a simple variable to activate bracketed paste?"* Because the idea is that a terminal should "advertise" that it has the bracketed paste capability and Vim should simply respect that setting from the terminal. But the way terminals are configured is through terminfo database entries and the `$TERM` variable. Unfortunately that makes for quite a messy setup where you need to keep everything in sync to do it right. Vim offers the `t_*` settings so that you can override low level entries from your terminal.

Comment: @filbranden this doesn't seem to be the case. I have gnome terminal 3.30 but the `TERM` variable was empty before setting it up today.

Comment: Yeah, the `t_*` entries are mostly a hack, but they're often helpful when you want to make sure your setup will work in many different systems, with possibly outdated terminfo databases, that are quite hard to fix on your own... So while setting the `t_*` options in Vim is far from ideal, many times they're the pragmatic route to get what you want to work working. (I have had to `set t_Co=256` myself before, which we talked about in a different question...)

Comment: "Because the idea is that a terminal should "advertise" that it has the bracketed paste capability " In light of the potential other side effects of lying about Xterm, I'm wondering why is there not a specific environment variable to advertise that capability?

Comment: @PaulRougieux *"the `TERM` variable was empty before setting it up today."* That's most certainly a **bug**!!! And I don't think it's a bug in GNOME Terminal or anything, but most likely in one of your initialization files (`.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` or similar) or system initialization files (`/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`, etc.) Unfortunately it's probably hard to trace where that's coming from... But try to use `grep` and see if you find anything touching `TERM` that could be the reason why that was set incorrectly that way!

Comment: @filbranden the only thing I find are conditions `grep TERM /etc/profile.d/*
/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh:case "$TERM" in` 
`grep TERM .bashrc
case "$TERM" in`
`case "$TERM" in`

Comment: @PaulRougieux Maybe try GNOME Terminal custom command of `/bin/bash --noprofile --norc` and see if `$TERM` is still empty? Or set `$TERM` to something like `xterm-256color` and start a new shell with `/bin/bash -l` and see if it's empty again on the new shell?

Comment: @PaulRougieux Actually that `vte-2.91.sh` looks suspicious... What else does it do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108028/discussion-between-paul-rougieux-and-filbranden).

Answer (score 1):

This was because I was calling vim inside a tmux session and the `$TERM` environment variable is equal to "screen" in tmux.

### Recommended way

As explained in `:h xterm-bracketed-paste` and in the other answer above, you can add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Activate bracketed paste in tmux
if &term =~ "screen"
  let &t_BE = "\e[?2004h"
  let &t_BD = "\e[?2004l"
  exec "set t_PS=\e[200~"
  exec "set t_PE=\e[201~"
endif
```

After that vim bracketed paste mode becomes enabled also when vim is inside tmux.

### Not recommended way

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355391/85530) and the [tmux FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-256-colour-terminal).

> Provided the underlying terminal supports 256 colours, it is usually sufficient to add one of the following to `~/.tmux.conf`:
>
> ```
>   set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
> ```

By default, vim doesn't recognize "screen-256color" as a terminal compatible with bracketed paste, so I changed the setting to

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

After that vim recognized the terminal as compatible with bracketed paste mode.

Comment: Setting `'default-terminal'` to anything other than "screen", "tmux" or a derivative of these 2 values is wrong.  It may "fix" your issue, but it will create many other issues.  See [the tmux man page](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#default-terminal): *For tmux to work correctly, this must be set to ‘screen', ‘tmux' or a derivative of them.*

Comment: @user938271 Thanks, I figured out that `TERM=xterm-256color` is set by default inside gnome terminal. But tmux overwrites it to `TERM=screen`. If setting 'default-terminal' is frowned upon, what is the recommended way to carry over `TERM=xterm-256color`  to tmux? And with respect to the OP, what is the recommended way to make vim aware that this is an `xterm-256color` compatible session so that bracketed paste works.

Comment: I’ve had better luck with tmux or tmux-256color (manually compiled) as TERM—tmux requires a screen or tmux variant.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble with `~/.tmux.conf` setting `set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"`, I still have the issue mentioned in the OP. Only `set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"` solves the issue.

Comment: @PaulRougieux *But tmux overwrites it to TERM=screen* Yes, and that's correct. *If setting 'default-terminal' is frowned upon, what is the recommended way to carry over TERM=xterm-256color to tmux?* There is no recommended way, because doing so is wrong.

Comment: @PaulRougieux *And with respect to the OP, what is the recommended way to make vim aware that this is an xterm-256color compatible session so that bracketed paste works.* I guess you could try to install a shell alias (`alias myvim='TERM=xterm-256color vim'`), but I would not do that; I would not lie to Vim about the identity of the terminal. If you want to enable bracketed paste mode in a terminal other than xterm, you need to set terminal options; this is explained at `:h xterm-bracketed-paste`.

Comment: @PaulRougieux again, you may need to compile a terminfo for tmux-256color yourself.

Comment: OK I read `:h xterm-bracketed-paste` removed the .tmux.conf setting of default-terminal (which means it falls back to "$TERM=screen") and added ` if &term =~ "screen"   let &t_BE = "\e[?2004h" etc... ` to `.vimrc` which seems to be the better way to do it.